# Send variable from c++ to mysql

Tags: c++, mysql, variables

I want to send a string variable to a mysql database so that database uses a query with my variable and finds something in the database.Also the database/query needs to send me back another variable which i can use it in my c++.

I probably need to find how to connect the c++ with the mysql also and how exactly i can send this variable to the query.

How do you advice me to do this?

LE:
I've found this and covers preety much exactly what i need to do:

```
#include <mysql.h>
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    MYSQL *conn;
    MYSQL_RES *res;
    MYSQL_ROW row;
    char *server = "server";
    char *user = "user";
    char *password = "password";  // got tot keep my data secret
    char *database = "cpp_test";
    conn = mysql_init(NULL);

// connect to database
if(!mysql_real_connect(conn, server, user, password, database, 0, NULL, 0))
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
    return -1;
}

// send SQL query
if(mysql_query(conn, "select * from cpp_testTAB"))
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
    return -1;
}

res = mysql_use_result(conn);

// output table name
printf("MySQL Tables in mysql database:\n");
while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) != NULL)
{
    printf("%s %s %s %s\n", row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3]);
}

// close connection
mysql_free_result(res);
mysql_close(conn);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk : Not realy,no. Because i dont need to know exactly how to add stuff to the database, only how to connect.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the [MySQL C API](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/c-api.html). Your program will send `INSERT` or `UPDATE` queries to modify tables in the MySQL database, and `SELECT` queries to read something from the tables.

Mind that using a C API is not at all trivial for a C++ beginner. You will need knowledge of C, C++ and SQL to reach your goals.

Comment: For the moment i'm working with somebody who is doing the sql part of the project. I only need to know how to connect/send to him some data then he will do his magic and he will return to me what i need.